# CSS - getting width from a DIV before the last one

Tags: css, width, jquery-select2

I have a Select2 element on a page with a button at right and I want the Select2 take all the space except what the button takes. The problem is that Select2 injects its own formatting once activated and I can't figure out how to go around this.

Here is what I have:

```
<ul style="width:100%">
 <li>
  <label style="display:inline">From: </label>
  <div class="select2-container select2-container-multi test" style="width:0px">
  <ul class="select2-choices">...
```

I want select2-choices to be 90% of first ul but if I put

```
.test .select2-choices {
    width:90%;
}
```

then it gives me 90% of previous div which is 0px. Is there a way I can get the width for "select2-choices" from the first ul, not from the parent div?

Comment: You can easily use Javascript (jQuery) to accomplish this task, but I'm not sure if you are looking for a CSS only solution.   If you can use jQuery in your project I'll add an answer below.

Comment: Javascript would be fine too, whatever makes it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with CSS. You'll need to use some javascript for that. Is there a particular reason you need your parent to have a 0px width?

Edit:
You could do something like this in jQuery. I don't recommend hard coding the percentage but this should get you going.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).on('resize',function(){
       var $choices = $('.select2-choices');
       var parentWidth = $choices.parents('ul').width();
       $choices.width(parentWidth*.9);        
    }).trigger('resize');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BAGkD/

Comment: that parent div gets injected by Select2 input element for some reason, probably to store a data or something, I do not control it.

Comment: I couldn't make it work for window resize but I have an idea to get the width in px and put it directly to div style. But if I do: console.log($('select2-choices').parents('ul').width()); - I get 100 which is probably mean 100%. Do you know if I can get that figure in pixels?

Comment: .width() will return the pixel value regardless of your CSS declaration. However a caveat to that is the element must have finished loading. Make sure you wrap your javascript in a document ready function or declare it after your elements.

http://api.jquery.com/width/

Comment: I got it. You are right, I couln't measure befire the elemet comes up. I put that your code in $('#modal').on('shown') and in $('#modal').on('resize') and it is working great now. Thank you.